# How to use View Binding insted of butterknife?

Tags: android, android-studio, view, android-databinding, android-viewbinding

I am updating an app. In the new program, I intend to use View Binding because butterknife library does not work. My codes are as follows. How do I use the new method?
The previous code uses the butterknife library. By updating the program to a new version, it is not possible to use this library and sync it. After a little searching, I found out that the better solution is to use method two. But I have a problem in rewriting the codes. If possible, guide in making the necessary changes.
Thanks

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/baseDialog_imgDialog"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/baseDialog_imgDialog"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/baseDialog_imgDialog"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/baseDialog_tvTitle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/baseDialog_tvDescription"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:weightSum="2.5">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/baseDialog_btnNo"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/bkg_blue_curved"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/baseDialog_btnYes"

                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/strocked_simple"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.example.R;
import com.example.interfase.MyClickHolder;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;


public class TowOptionDialog extends BaseDialog {
    private String noButtonText, yesButtonText, titleText, bodyText;
    private Drawable imageLink;

    MyClickHolder myClickHolde;

    public void setMyClickHolde(MyClickHolder myClickHolde) {
        this.myClickHolde = myClickHolde;
    }

    @BindView(R.id.baseDialog_tvTitle)
    TextView tvTitle;

    @BindView(R.id.baseDialog_tvDescription)
    TextView tvDescription;

    @BindView(R.id.baseDialog_btnNo)
    TextView btnNo;

    @BindView(R.id.baseDialog_btnYes)
    TextView btnYes;

    @BindView(R.id.baseDialog_imgDialog)
    ImageView imgBaseDialog;

    @OnClick(R.id.baseDialog_btnYes)
    void yesButton() {
        myClickHolde.onClicked(null, 1);
        dismiss();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.baseDialog_btnNo)
    void noButton() {
        dismiss();

    }


    public TowOptionDialog(@NonNull Context context,
                           String noButtonText,
                           String yesButtonText,
                           String titleText,
                           String bodyText,
                           Drawable imageLink) {
        super(context);
        this.noButtonText = noButtonText;
        this.yesButtonText = yesButtonText;
        this.titleText = titleText;
        this.bodyText = bodyText;
        this.imageLink = imageLink;
    }

    public TowOptionDialog(@NonNull Context context,
                           String titleText,
                           String bodyText
    ) {
        super(context);
        this.noButtonText = "No";
        this.yesButtonText = "Yes";
        this.titleText = titleText;
        this.bodyText = bodyText;
        this.imageLink = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_two_button);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        tvTitle.setText(titleText);
        tvDescription.setText(bodyText);
        imgBaseDialog.setImageDrawable(imageLink);
        imgBaseDialog.setVisibility(imageLink == null
                ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE
        );
        btnYes.setText(yesButtonText);
        btnNo.setText(noButtonText);
    }
```

Comment: Before going into details, I don't know the limits of your current app, have you considered using compose if you are regardless modernising?
Anyway about this, A good start is https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding, it will tell you step by step.
As for now, you need to indicate in your gradle script to enable viewBinding as indicated in the docs.
After that, rebuild your project and access with the name of the desired layout xml file to your views.
Remember a good practice as indicated in the documentation to nullify your member variable if you did in fact used one.

Answer (score 0):

First remove your existing Butterknife library and add viewBinding to your build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

Then you have to setup your root view,
create a Global variable something like this:

`private ActivityMainBinding binding`

For example, I have if I am using my MainActivity viewBinding autogenerate someting like this "ActivityMainBinding", you can then initialize this variable in your onCreate function.

```
private ActivityMainBinding binding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    // Now you can access your views using the binding object
    binding.tvHeader.setText("Hello, ViewBinding!");
}
```

After the initailization then you can call any of your widget with their respective ID, For example, I have called my TextView 'tvHeader' using binding like this `binding.tvHeader.setText("Hello, ViewBinding!");`

Update:

To Handle button click with binding:

```
binding.baseDialogBtnYes.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    myClickHolde.onClicked(null, 1);
    dismiss();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But, how to handle this:  @OnClick(R.id.baseDialog_btnYes)
    void yesButton() {
        myClickHolde.onClicked(null, 1);
        dismiss();
    }

Comment: @AliHoseinpour I have updated my code, to handle button click, Please check it out!